# How do you extract images from a RSS feed with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, rss

I'm trying to use RSS feed articles on my website, but the featured image is not showing up. The title and summary do show up. I just started using javaScript so i'm not sure what i did wrong.
Thanks in advance.
I'm trying to use RSS feed articles on my website, but the featured image is not showing up. The title and summary do show up. I just started using javaScript so i'm not sure what i did wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Here's my js code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
$(function () {
    var $content = $('#roundupContent');
    var data = {
        rss_url: 'http://roundup.calpolycorporation.org/~api/papers/b686f300-0de4-458f-9b51-07756c12d705/rss'
    };
    $.get('https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json', data, function (response) {
        if (response.status == 'ok') {
            var output = '';
            $.each(response.items, function (k, item) {

                output += '<div class="post-card category-medium published">';
                //output += '<h3 class="date">' + $.format.date(item.pubDate, "dd<br>MMM") + "</h4>";
                var tagIndex = item.description.indexOf('<media:content'); // Find where the media:content tag starts
                var urlIndex = item.description.substring(tagIndex).indexOf('url=') + tagIndex; // Find where the url attribute starts
                var urlStart = urlIndex + 5; // Find where the actual image URL starts; 5 for the length of 'url="'
                var urlEnd = item.description.substring(urlStart).indexOf('"') + urlStart; // Find where the URL ends
                var url = item.description.substring(urlStart, urlEnd); // Extract just the URL
                output += '<p class="post-meta">';
                //output += '<span class="published">' + item.pubDate + '</span>';
                output += '<a href="http://roundup.calpolycorporation.org/~api/papers/b686f300-0de4-458f-9b51-07756c12d705/rss" target="_blank">@roundup.calpolycorporation.org</span></a>';
                output += '</p>';

                output += '<h2 class="entry-title">' + item.title + '</h2>';
                //output += '<div class="post-meta"><span>By ' + item.author + '</span></div>';
                var yourString = item.description.replace(/<media:content[^>]*>/g, ""); //replace with your string.
                var maxLength = 300 // maximum number of characters to extract
                //trim the string to the maximum length
                var trimmedString = yourString.substr(0, maxLength);
                //re-trim if we are in the middle of a word
                trimmedString = trimmedString.substr(0, Math.min(trimmedString.length, trimmedString.lastIndexOf(" ")))

                output += '<div class="excerpt">' + trimmedString + '</div>';
                output += '<a href="' + item.link + '" class="more-link cpc-button activeghostdark small">Read More</a>';
                output += '<a class="entry-featured-image-url" href="' + item.link + '"><img url="' + url + '"></a>';

                output += '</div>';
                return k < 1;
            });
            $content.html(output);
        }
    });
});
});
```

Here's part of the RSS feed code

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <generator>Paper.li RSS generator</generator>
        <title>Cal Poly Corporation Roundup</title>
        <link>https://paper.li/CPCorporation/1478016962</link>
        <atom:link href="http://roundup.calpolycorporation.org/~api/papers/b686f300-0de4-458f-9b51-07756c12d705/rss" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml"></atom:link>
        <description>Cal Poly, the CSU and higher education news from around the web</description>
        <image>
            <url>https://s3.amazonaws.com/avatars.paper.li/paper_avatars/492d64db-5677-41cb-a438-f3f19399d6bb/9rdccload70ueqtiyvna/0315_CPC_PaperliRoundup_Skin_v1_PaperThumbnail2.png</url>
            <title>Cal Poly Corporation Roundup</title>
            <link>https://paper.li/CPCorporation/1478016962</link>
        </image>
        <ttl>180</ttl>
        <pubDate>Fri, 13 Jul 2018 21:25:48 +0000</pubDate>
        <lastBuildDate>Fri, 13 Jul 2018 21:25:48 +0000</lastBuildDate>
        <item>
            <title>Freshman SLO Days | New Student &amp; Transition Programs</title>
            <link>https://orientation.calpoly.edu/student-life-orientation-days/2016-schedule</link>
            <description>&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;orientation.calpoly.edu&lt;/strong&gt; - Wondering how to get started with SLO Days? Follow these steps to secure your spot and begin the first part of your Cal Poly journey! Accept your Offer of Admission from Cal Poly through your Cal Polâ€¦&lt;/p&gt;&lt;br/&gt;Tweeted by @CPPrezArmstrong https://twitter.com/CPPrezArmstrong/status/1015631541530234881</description>
            <guid isPermaLink="false">0c5e1132-71e2-492d-a327-cdef80d0fd32</guid>
            <category>Leisure</category>
            <media:content url="https://content-calpoly-edu.s3.amazonaws.com/orientation/1/images/our-team/orientation-team/freshmanSloDays_0.jpg" medium="image"></media:content>
            <pubDate>Sat, 07 Jul 2018 16:20:03 +0000</pubDate>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code where you actually make an `img` tag.

Comment: Opps, i just added it to the last output line, but it still didn't work.